# is there a transform matrix in svg so x becomes y and y becomes x?

Tags: javascript, math, svg, npm

I'm working with [svgpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgpath) to manipulate svgs and,I need to change the coordonate system so that y becomes x and x becomes y. My question is there any  way to do it. I tried to  rotate  around points 0 0 and translating by the figure by its height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a svg transform attribute, it is

```
transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)"
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="100"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="pos" >
    <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M20,80 V20 H80 M20,20 80,80" />
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="80" cy="20" r="10" fill="yellow" />
    <circle cx="20" cy="80" r="10" fill="green" />
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="10" fill="blue" />
  </symbol>
  <!-- transposed -->
  <use xlink:href="#pos" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)" />
  <!-- original, but moved to the side for comparison -->
  <use xlink:href="#pos" transform="translate(150)" />
</svg>
```

In svgpath syntax,

```
svgpath(__your_path__).matrix([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: you are absolutly right about this transformation do you have any reference i can read to understand it fully ?

Comment: Read the spec: [Coordinate system transformations](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace)

Answer (score 0):

The operation you want requires changing the [orientation aka "handedness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)) and this requires using of negative scale. Just rotations and usual scaling/skewing preserve the orientation. One way to achieve this is to scale X by -1 (i.e. invert X) and then rotate everything by 90° clockwise. I haven't tried it but something like this should work:

```
var transformed = svgpath(__your_path__)
                  .scale(-1.0, 1.0) //scale only X but not Y
                  .rotate(90) 
                  .toString();
```

Comment: thank you SergGr your answer is right but the transform matrix was more straightforward for me. ultimatly the scale and rotate are just applying transform matrix internally and i want to understand it to really know what i'm doing.

Comment: @bakaoubaka, I agree that depending on your level of understanding direct matrix might be more straightforward. And of course the combination of negative scale + rotate should result in exactly that matrix. But I guessed that if you understood transformation matrix well enough, you'd got that answer yourself. Still I've actually upvoted that answer too.